# Troubleshooting rsyslog 8.32 on Ubuntu writing to MariaDB

Tags: rsyslog, rsyslogd

I am trying to get LogAnalyzer running and setup the system based on [How to setup loganalyzer with rsyslog on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](http://yallalabs.com/linux/how-to-setup-loganalyzer-with-rsyslog-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-ubuntu-18-04-lts/). It went smoothly up until the first of LogAnalyzer when it failed saying that the database table has no data.  I have looked and it is right, for whatever reason, rsyslog is not writing to the database (MariaDB 15.1), and I am at a loss to understand why.  Here is my mysql.conf (*pwd* is my password, and I have verified the DB login data before.):

```
module (load="ommysql")
*.* action(type="ommysql" server="localhost" db="Syslog" uid="rsyslog" pwd="*pwd*")
```

I have run debugging on rsyslog and here are some snippets:

```
4945.357999570:main thread    : rainerscript.c:         name: 'load', value 'ommysql'
4945.358021444:main thread    : rainerscript.c: nvlstGetParam: name 'load', type 13, valnode->bUsed 0
4945.358038361:main thread    : modules.c: modulesProcessCnf params:
4945.358053527:main thread    : rainerscript.c: load:  'ommysql'
4945.358092317:main thread    : modules.c: Requested to load module 'ommysql'
4945.358116817:main thread    : modules.c: loading module '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/rsyslog/ommysql.so'
4945.376069860:main thread    : modules.c: module ommysql of type 1 being loaded (keepType=0).
4945.376135775:main thread    : ommysql.c: entry point 'setModCnf' not present in module
4945.376153858:main thread    : modules.c: module config name is 'ommysql'
4945.376169608:main thread    : ommysql.c: entry point 'beginCnfLoad' not present in module
4945.376237564:main thread    : ommysql.c: entry point 'doHUP' not present in module
4945.376253314:main thread    : ommysql.c: entry point 'doHUPWrkr' not present in module
4945.376268480:main thread    : ommysql.c: entry point 'SetShutdownImmdtPtr' not present in module
4945.376283938:main thread    : ommysql.c: entry point 'doAction' not present in module
4945.376299396:main thread    : ommysql.c: entry point 'endTransaction' not present in module
4945.380317284:main thread    : rainerscript.c: nvlstGetParam: name 'type', type 14, valnode->bUsed 0
4945.380507737:main thread    : ../action.c: action param blk after actionNewInst:
4945.380530195:main thread    : rainerscript.c: name: (unset)
4945.380567527:main thread    : rainerscript.c: type:  'ommysql'
4945.380607484:main thread    : rainerscript.c: action.errorfile: (unset)
4945.380644233:main thread    : rainerscript.c: action.writeallmarkmessages: (unset)
4945.380679816:main thread    : rainerscript.c: action.execonlyeverynthtime: (unset)
4945.380715398:main thread    : rainerscript.c: action.execonlyeverynthtimetimeout: (unset)
4945.380751272:main thread    : rainerscript.c: action.execonlyonceeveryinterval: (unset)
```

And one more:

```
4945.396148220:main thread    : ../template.c: Template: Name=' StdDBFmt' [SQL-Format (MySQL)] 
4945.396203635:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6dec70): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: 'insert into SystemEvents (Message, Facility, FromHost, Priority, DeviceReportedTime, ReceivedAt, InfoUnitID, SysLogTag) values (''
4945.396243009:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6ded30): type 2, (FIELD), value: '1' 
4945.396280925:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6deea0): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: '', '
4945.396319424:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6def60): type 2, (FIELD), value: '12' 
4945.396357048:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df0d0): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: ', ''
4945.396395255:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df190): type 2, (FIELD), value: '3' 
4945.396434045:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df300): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: '', '
4945.396472253:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df3c0): type 2, (FIELD), value: '14' 
4945.396511335:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df530): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: ', ''
4945.396549542:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df5f0): type 2, (FIELD), value: '2' [Format as MySQL-Date] [COMPLEX]
4945.396610207:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df760): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: '', ''
4945.396648123:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df820): type 2, (FIELD), value: '16' [Format as MySQL-Date] [COMPLEX]
4945.396708496:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6df990): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: '', '
4945.396747287:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6dfa50): type 2, (FIELD), value: '11' 
4945.396786369:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6dfbc0): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: ', ''
4945.396823701:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6dfc80): type 2, (FIELD), value: '4' 
4945.396862784:main thread    : ../template.c:  Entry(556f6dfdf0): type 1, (CONSTANT), value: '')'
```

I am not sure if this provides enough information and would be happy to share more if that would be helpful.  I am struggling to figure out how to troubleshoot this and appreciate any suggestions from the experts here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and wanted to share the answer in case anyone had the same problem.  Specifically, I had the following line in my config:

& ~

For whatever reason, that was causing the error and removing the line fixed the problem.